# Effect of duplicate/redundant labels on performance of model

Tags: regression, dataset, overfitting

I am training a CNN to predict age,mass and tone from images.

The structure of my dateset is as follows

```
Person 1
20 images belonging to one person.The person's age,mass and tone remains the same in these images,with only difference being that in each image,the person has been translated by a certain amount.
Person 2
Similar structure to person 1 but with different age,mass and tone
.
.
.
.
Person 500
```

In all there are 10,000 images and 10,000 json files(that contain information about the age,mass and tone).

While training the model and then testing it via R2 score,I observed that for new samples sometimes the R2 score would come out to be negative.

I have tried the standard approaches to dealing with over fitting such as dropout,regularization
reducing number of epochs,reducing the model.But there has been no improvement.

This leads me to conclude that the presence of the extra 19 annotation files which all contain the same age,mass and tone might be responsible for over fitting,and prevents the network from learning the full distribution of the age,mass and tone parameters.

As such ,I wanted to know if my approach of thinking is correct here.Does the presence of redundant training samples cause over fitting and prevent model from generalizing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How did you obtain the true labels for age, mass (weight?) and tone (skin color??).

Comment: true labels were given to me by dataset design team who are using a 3d software.Sorry can't reveal more about the process ,but I can say that in person_1 all 20 images have the same true label

Comment: You are asking for help to categorize age, weight and skin color of (I assume) real people from images. How you came up with the labels and even more importantly -- what do you intend to do with a model like this -- are actually very relevant questions. "We have a super secret process" is a flaky answer.

Comment: I understand your point of view because in order to answer the question you would need to understand the process of how the data was created which is okay.But I am bound by confidentiality agreements.So i hope you understand my predicament also.